# How to redirect on validate route in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to redirect if a page after validate its query is wrong. How could I achieve this ? Here is my code

```
validate({ params, query, router }){
    if(isAfter(new Date(query.date_check_in), addDays(new Date(), 1)) !== true) {
      query.date_check_in = format(addDays(new Date(), 1), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      query.date_check_out = format(addDays(new Date(), 2), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      return true
    } else if(query.date_check_in === 'Invalid Date' || query.date_check_out === 'Invalid Date') {
      router.push('search')
      return true
    }
  }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You might also want to `return false;` if both check fail

Answer (score 5):

you can use 'redirect'

for example:

```
validate({ store, redirect }) {
    // some codes...
    redirect('/')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[It's recommended](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle) to redirect from middleware. You just need to create a middleware, e.g. `src/middleware/redirect.js`.

```js
export default function({ app, redirect }) {
    // Option 1: your store isn't reset
    app.router.push(`/`);

    // Option 2: an actual redirect (check status code), which will also reset Vuex store 
    redirect('301', '/', {});
}
```

Then, from your page...

```js
export default {
    middleware: [
        'redirect',
    ],
},
```

---

You can push to router as follows (remember `validate()` should return [either boolean or promise](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-validate)):

```js
validate({ app }) {
    app.router.push('/');

    return true;
},
```